# Rails 4.1.0.beta1 not loading smtp_settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm trying to send emails with rails 4.1.0.beta1, and it is not loading the smtp_settings that are configured at development.rb.

Testing in the console, I see that my ReceiptMailer.smtp_settings are "empty", but the Rails.application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings is correct with the development.rb settings.

I'm having to set ReceiptMailer.smtp_settings = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings before I send to get it working, but it is pretty much an unwanted behavior.

Is this a version specific problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think I maaaaayyyy be having the same problem... Did you figure it out?

Comment: Brandon, I'm using the approach I listed above. I think I'm going to open an issue on rails' github.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13372 This is an issue and is fixed for the next rails 4.1.0 release.